# MySQL HTML sanitization

Tags: mysql, sanitize, html-sanitizing, sanitization

I have a website that saves data to a MySQL database

Should I escape the HTML upon inserting it into MySQL or upon displaying it on my website?

Ideally, I'd like to input raw HTML into my database and just sanitize each time I pull from it. Is there any danger in doing it this way?

Example html:`<h1>test</h1>`

Comment: Escape HTML for what? If you have `<a href="http://example.com">Click me</a>` and you manipulate it you'll probably break it. If you have `Barnes & Noble` and need to convert it to `Barnes &amp; Noble` to display in on a web site it's because you do not have HTML in the first place. (The term "sanitizacion" is one of my pet peeves. It implies that some strings are bad by nature but you can apply some magic function to them and make them safe for any purpose.)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I updated the answer above typically users won't save HTML, but I don't want them to be restricted. Of course that HTML won't be executed. It will just be displayed as is

Comment: Do you mean you want to see the actual HTML tags (a literal `<h1>test</h1>` text) on the page, as opposed to seeing a title with `test` in a large font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> typically users won't save HTML, but I don't want them to be
> restricted. Of course that HTML won't be executed. It will just be
> displayed
>
> Should I escape the HTML upon inserting it into MySQL or upon displaying it on my website?

Then you don't have HTML to begin with. You have plain text.

Escaping plain text to be injected in HTML is a fast operation and, unless we're talking of 1 GB worth of text in a single row, it doesn't make sense to cache it. If you convert to plain text to HTML before saving it, you no longer have the original text and you're forced to *undo* the encoding just to *not* use it in HTML context (e.g., put it in a JavaScript variable or use it as e-mail subject).