# How to sanitize data received from WYSIWYG Editor?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, wysiwyg

I have a typical WYSIWYG editor for a blog, which has the ability to embed youtube videos and videos from some other commonly known sources. the editor is JavaScript based. And it adds too much of html tags and java-script in the content that I receive. As i have to store this data received from the editor in my MySQL database. I want to sanitize it. What is the best way to sanitize this data and make it safe to store in the database and further deal with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL HTML sanitization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141978/mysql-html-sanitization)

Comment: @pringi it is not duplicate. in this question, it is not just about html sanitization but also javascript sanitization.

Answer (score 1):

You can define which tags you would like to allow and then filter out the other tags in p easily:

```
 $allowedTags='<p><strong><em><u><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><img>';
 $allowedTags.='<li><ol><ul><span><div><br><ins><del>';
 $receivedData = $_POST['textFromEditor'];
 $sContent = strip_tags(stripslashes($receivedData),$allowedTags);
```

Comment: this works only aboutt html elements. But what about javascript? I want to remove javascript too from the data i receive from the editor.

Comment: sure that is simple give the `<script>` tags too.. A javascript won't execute unless it is in those tags.

Comment: Useful to avoid html injection and only show html information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to re-invent the wheel. 
An adequate class to achieve this is [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Comment: htmlpurifier only sanitizes html tags. but what about javascript elements? I don't want any javascript code in the data i receive from the wysiwyg editor, and even if i receive, i want to sanitize and remove such things.